# Random "comp not bound" error (JBoss4/EJB3)

Tags: jboss, jmx, mbeans, seam2, jboss-4.2.x

I have this very odd error. The EAR is deployed fine. The error appears during certain jobs (like background tasks) and it complains about not being able to instantiate components that were used just fine seconds earlier by the same code. Nothing expired (session or transaction) as far as I can tell, the time when it appears is random and I can't reproduce the error each time.

JBoss4.2.3, JDK7, Seam 2.2.0GA, EJB3.

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: org.jboss.seam.InstantiationException: Could not instantiate Seam component: translationService
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.Ejb3TxPolicy.handleExceptionInOurTx(Ejb3TxPolicy.java:63)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:83)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$RequiresNew.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:253)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:95)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:62)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.aspects.security.AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:77)
at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.java:110)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:46)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.AsynchronousInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:106)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.localInvoke(StatelessContainer.java:240)
at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.localInvoke(StatelessContainer.java:210)
at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessLocalProxy.invoke(StatelessLocalProxy.java:84)
at $Proxy1264.runInTransaction(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4421.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.ClientSideInterceptor$1.proceed(ClientSideInterceptor.java:76)
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
at org.jboss.seam.intercept.ClientSideInterceptor.invoke(ClientSideInterceptor.java:54)
...
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: comp not bound
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:529)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:537)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:543)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:267)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:667)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:627)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at org.jboss.seam.Component.instantiateSessionBean(Component.java:1400)
at org.jboss.seam.Component.instantiate(Component.java:1364)
at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2122)
... 300 more
```

Sometimes the error changes to: 
`Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: comp.ejb3 not bound`

Comment: After many days of all kinds of tests, found the error is directly related to the activation of remote JMX. We read some platform MBeans, plus a custom MBean we defined (which appears to be the culprit somehow).